# SQL Server 2014 In Memory Table Creation Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I create an in-memory table, I get this error:

> The data types `char(n)` and `varchar(n)` using a collation that has a code page other than 1252 are not supported with memory optimized tables

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn133182.aspx

Comment: Can you add the sql query used for it

Comment: CREATE TABLE DummyTable_Mem (
 ID INT NOT NULL
 ,NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ID_Clust_DummyTable_Mem PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH (ID) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1000000)
 )
 WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem with this link: http://www.yigitaktan.com/archives/492

The problem's source is that: Sql Server instance's collation was Turkish_CI_AS. Memory-Optimized processes haven't supported my collation.

SELECT NAME AS [Collation]
    ,COLLATIONPROPERTY(NAME, 'codepage') AS [CodePage]
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE COLLATIONPROPERTY(NAME, 'codepage') = 1252

This query lists supported collations.